# jQuery .load not working in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am trying to do a jQuery AJAX call on a ASP.Net MVC page.  I can step through the call back function in my debugger and see that the javascript is executing, but the  does not update.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MenuContent" runat="server">

<% Html.RenderPartial("homeMenu"); %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    InitHomeMenu('homeMenu', function (menuItem) {
        var id = menuItem.attr('id');
        if (id = 'menuMission') {
            $('homeContent').load('Home/Mission');
        }
        else if (id = 'menuSuggestions') {
            $('homeContent').load('Home/Suggestions');
        }

    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div id="homeContent">
        <% string control = ViewData["Control"] != null ? ViewData["Control"].ToString() : "Mission";
        Html.RenderPartial(control); %>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

The call to `$('homeContent').load()` is working.  I can confirm I have data, but the div does not update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing the = with ==

```
if (id = 'menuMission')
```

with

```
if (id == 'menuMission')
```

Comment: Thanks, and for the record I did also have to put the # symbol back in like David suggested.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that `homeContent` is the id of the div you need to prefix it with a hash:

```
 $('#homeContent').load('Home/Mission');
```

If it's the class then prefix it with a period:

```
$('.homeContent').load('Home/Mission');
```

JQuery uses CSS selectors.

--

If your AJAX call is failing then it will do so silently (you might be getting an error 500 from the server, this is hidden on AJAX calls unless you hook up an error delegate on the full `.ajax` JQuery method).

Check that data is being returned from the server using something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Comment: Thanks, it is the id.  I started with the hash, tried again, then changed 'homeContent' to be a class and tried with the period.  None of it works.  The JavaScript executes without errors.

Comment: You might still be getting server errors, the script won't throw that. Try monitoring the web traffic using something like Fiddler2 to check that the data is being returned.